# Calculating corners coordinate from World file(.jgw)

Tags: world-file

I am trying to add an image layer into Azure map from World file, but having problem from calculating corners coordinate.

content of: .jgw

```
2.18004e-007        A
0                   D
0                   B
-1.13825e-007       E
15.17621696622324   C
58.59020007555156   F
```

where: 2.18004e-007=0.000000218004 and -1.13825e-007=-0.000000113825

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file (see calculation logic in right side) I calculated coordiates for other corners:

Formula:

```
(x,y)=(C,F)
(x1,y) = (A + C, F)
(x,y1) = (C, E + F;)
(x1,y1) = (A + C, E + F)
```

Results:

```
(x,y) = (15.17621696622324, 58.59020007555156)
(x1,y) = (15.17621718422724, 58.59020007555156)
(x,y1) = (15.17621696622324, 58.590199961726555)
(x1,y1) = (15.17621718422724, 58.590199961726555)
```

which seems not correct.any idea?

Comment: You need to take into account how many rows and columns your raster has. The upper left is X = C and Y = F (see http://webhelp.esri.com/arcims/9.3/General/topics/author_world_files.htm) then your lower right X = C + Cols * A, Y = F + Rows * E. Note a GDAL GeoTransform is different in the order of parameters https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html C, A, D, F, B, E.

Comment: Cols and Rows are dimention of the image?

Comment: Yes, in pixels. Each pixel takes up a box of A wide and F deep; F is usually negative as the *hook point* is upper left and pixels descend from this corner. Theoretically F can be positive if C and F are the coordinates of the lower left corner but as most rasters read from top left it makes more sense to use the 0,0 of the cells as the *hook point* and read cells away from this location.

Comment: `gdalinfo` will give you the corner coordinates directly

Comment: Able to make it works, Thanks guys.